# How to re-organize the table in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, table

Consider the following table:

```
tab=RandomReal[{0,1},{5,10}]
```

How is it possible to convert it into the form of a 2-column table `tab1` where each subsequent 5 rows `tab1[[i]],tab1[[i+1]],tab1[[i+2]],tab1[[i+3]],tab1[[i+4]]` are

```
{tab[[i]][[1]], tab[[i]][[2]]}
{tab[[i]][[3]], tab[[i]][[4]]}
{tab[[i]][[5]], tab[[i]][[6]]}
{tab[[i]][[7]], tab[[i]][[8]]}
{tab[[i]][[9]], tab[[i]][[10]]}
```

It may be some way of using `Riffle`. Say,

```
tab1 = tab[[All, {1, 2}]];
Do[tabb = tab[[All, {i + 1, i + 2}]];
 tab1 = Riffle[tab1, tabb, i];
 , {i, 2, 5, 1}]
```

However, I am sure that there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first create some data:

```
SeedRandom[1];
tab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 10}]
```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Then we destroy the structure using Flatten and reshape the array using ArrayReshape:

```
 ArrayReshape[Flatten[tab], {25, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]